# HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after calling HttpContext.SignInAsync("schema-name", claimsPrincipal);

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-authentication

I am using multiple authentication schemes. Here is my Startup.cs code -

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //code

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Default";
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Default";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "O365OpenId";
        })
                .AddCookie("Default",options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                    options.Cookie.Name = "ip" + guid.ToString();
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/Denied";
                    
                })
                .AddCookie("External", options =>
                 {
                     options.LoginPath = "/Auth/External";
                     options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                     options.Cookie.Name = "ip" + guid.ToString();
                     options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/Denied";
                 })
                .AddOAuth("O365OpenId", options =>
                {
                    //options.Authority = "given";
                    options.ClientId = "given";
                    options.ClientSecret = "given";
                    options.CallbackPath = "/auth/callback";
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=select_account";
                    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/Denied";
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    //options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    //options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    //options.Scope.Add("user.read");
                    //options.Scope.Add("calendars.read");
                    options.SaveTokens = false;
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes., "picture");
                    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                    {
                        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                        {
                            if (context.AccessToken is { })
                            {
                                context.Identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", context.AccessToken));
                            }
                            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            var json = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                            context.RunClaimActions(json.RootElement);
                            
                    };
                });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {

            options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireRole("Admin");
            });

            options.AddPolicy("Regular&Admin", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireRole("Regular");
            });

            options.AddPolicy("External", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("External");
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireRole("External");
            });
        });
        
    }
```

When I sign in user using the "Default" scheme, I find that the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true after HttpContext.SignInAsync("schema-name", claimsPrincipal); method call. Here is the code for signing in -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Success(string returnUrl)
    {
        // code

                var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Default",claimsPrincipal);

                // more code
    }
```

[isAuthenticated is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSIkX.png)

But When I sign in user using "External" scheme, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false after HttpContext.SignInAsync("schema-name", claimsPrincipal); call. Here is the code for signing in -

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> External([FromQuery] string ReturnUrl, LoginOTP loginOTP, string email)
    {
        //code

            var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity);
            
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("External", claimsPrincipal);

            //code
    }
```

[IsAuthenticated is false.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHdaF.png)

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Why is the IsAuthenticated returning false?
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 authentication schemes

- the first one is cookie-based and you named it: "Default",
- the second one is also cookie-based and you named it: "External",
- the third one is OAhut-based and you named it: "O365OpenId",

when referring to one of these schemes you should use the names that you have created.

now the issue is, that you're creating a ClaimeIdentity with one scheme but you signing the user with a different scheme.

for the external method it should be like this:

```cs
var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "External");
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity);

// code ... 

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("External", claimsPrincipal);
```

now the claims principal will be associated with the "External" scheme and the user will be authenticated.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have changed the code. But I am still getting "IsAuthenticated" -> false.

Comment: if for example, an action is protected with one scheme and your user is authenticated using a different scheme then based on this action context the user is not authenticated if you checked the HttpContext.User property you will see that the claims are there but the user is not authenticated, so verify the User auth scheme to see in which context he is authenticated.
what you should do is,  if your user has finished the authentication using the external scheme you should authenticate the user using your default scheme.
consider using ASP Core identity, it will make your life easy